# Can't boot VDI image after converting qcow2 QEMU image

Tags: virtualbox, qemu

I try to launch a VirtualBox VDI image (obtained from a `qcow2` image created with QEMU). This image has been created with the following command, starting from

```
 qemu-img convert -f qcow2 -O vdi debian-9.0-sparc64.qcow2 debian-9.0-sparc64.vdi
```

Version of `qemu-img` is :

```
$ qemu-img --version
qemu-img version 2.9.0
```

But when I add the VDI image into VirtualBox, illustrated as below :

[image: adding debian-9 sparc 64]

and launch it, I get this message :

[image: FATAL error]

From what I have seen on similar FATAL errors, It seems that I have to add an ISO image of the OS, in addition to the `VDI` image created, doesn't it ?

I have an ISO image of Debian-9 Sparc64 (`debian-9.0-sparc64-NETINST-1.iso`) but this is an installation raw ISO image, not a current ISO image with an installed OS.

I tried to add this ISO image in configuration panel like this :

[image: Try to add raw ISO image]

and the ordering of boot devices :

[image: order of boot]

I have also tried to generate a VDI image from this [tutorial](http://www.whitemiceconsulting.com/node/37),
but without success.

For the moment, I can only launch the qcow2 image with QEMU like :

```
qemu-system-sparc64 -name debian-sparc64 -machine sun4u,accel=tcg,usb=off -m 1024 \
   -realtime mlock=off -smp 1,sockets=1,cores=1,threads=1 \
   -rtc base=utc -no-reboot -no-shutdown \
   -boot strict=on \
   -drive file=debian-9.0-sparc64.qcow2,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-1,format=qcow2,cache=none \
   -device ide-hd,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-1,id=ide0-0-1 \
   -netdev user,id=hostnet0,hostfwd=tcp::5555-:22 \
   -device e1000,netdev=hostnet0,id=net0,mac=52:54:00:ce:98:e8 \
   -msg timestamp=on -nographic
```

I was motivated to launch Debian 9 Sparc64 with VirtualBox because, with `qemu-system-sparc64`, I can't have network (but this is a different problem).

What might be wrong (to launch VirtualBox VDI image) or give some clues to fix this error message at boot ?

### Update 1

The issue seems to come from the conversion between `.qcow2` and VDI with `qemu-img` tool. How to make bootable a VDI disk ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBoxManage convertdd debian-9.0-sparc64.qcow2 linux_file.vdi